# Calculating range ratios of projectiles with or w/o lift for set time sub-intervals

Tags: dynamical-systems, applications, classical-mechanics, projectile-motion

### The question is as follows:

*Ignoring drag, a golf ball launched with neutral spin can be expected to follow a curve given by:*

*r(t) = (Vcos$\theta$t, Vsin$\theta$t - g$t^2$/2)*

*where V: launch speed, theta: launch angle, g: acc due to gravity, t: time*

*A simple model to incorporate lift force on the ball mass due to backspin is proposed as:*

*$F_{lift}$ = m$a_1$*

*....which switches off when t exceeds half the flight time (TOF) for the spin shot to simulate the ball slowing down. a1 is assumed constant. 
How much will the length of the golf shot be changed when backspin is considered?*

My answer was :  **$\frac{2}{1 - \frac{a_1}{2g}}$** however I'm not sure if it's correct.

### My procedure:

Derived a composite function for the vertical y displacement of the ball w/spin for the first half (see bottom) then w/o spin for the second half.

Into each equation, subbed in $\frac{TOF_{spin}}{2}$, summed the displacements and set = 0. (Overall y displacement is 0). Solved for $TOF_{spin}$.

Solved for $TOF_{nospin}$ then found ratio of TOFs and thus ratio of ranges as range=u.TOF

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

- ð $r_{y-spin}$(t) = Vsin$\theta$t + $\frac{1}{2}$($a_1$-g)$t^2$

### Calculations:

[Calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq3Dz.jpg)

However I think that I cannot sum the formulae as I have done here:

[Highlighted Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDnLB.jpg)

Comment: Could you include your calculations in your question? I think I might know what went wrong, but it would help if I could see your calculations. Btw, you can check that your answer probably isn't correct by looking at the limit $a_1 \to 0$, which should yield a change of zero of the length of the golf shot: instead, you get 2.

Comment: Yes that's why I figured it was incorrect, thank you. I'll edit the question now to show my calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is generally correct, but there's one problem: your flight path is discontinuous. For the $y$-coordinate of the ball, you wrote
\begin{equation}
 y(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} V\sin \theta\,t + \frac{1}{2}(a_1-g)t^2 & \text{if} & 0 < t \leq \frac{1}{2}T, \\ V\sin \theta\,t -\frac{1}{2}g t^2 & \text{if} & \frac{1}{2}T < t \leq T\end{array}\right. .
\end{equation}
However, at $t=T/2$, the ball suddenly drops from height $V \sin \theta T + \frac{1}{2}(a_1 - g) T^2$ to height $v \sin \theta T - \frac{1}{2} g T^2$. In other words, the second half of your flight path is not correct.

To remedy this, consider this question: what would the flight path be of a golf ball, starting at the coordinate $(x_0,y_0)$, launched with initial speed $W$ at an angle $\phi$? Note that your 'neutral' flight path belongs to a golf ball launched from the origin (i.e. $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$), at an angle $\theta$ with initial speed $V$.

Comment: I used **Wsin$\phi$t - $\frac{1}{2}$g$t^2$** in place of the incorrect half of the flight equation. I found two equations using this new form.   First was equating the y values at $\frac{T}{2}$ resulted in **Vsin$\theta$ + $\frac{a_1T}{4}$ = Wsin$\phi$**   Secondly, equating the x values at $\frac{T}{2}$ resulted in: **$\frac{V}{W}$=$\frac{cos\phi}{cos\theta}$**.  My answer was in the realms of my original one but agin did not make sense.  Is this an incorrect method or am I simply making calculation errors?  Many Thanks

Comment: Look again at the last part of my answer. If you start at a given point $(x_0,y_0)$ with initial velocity $(W \cos \phi, W \sin \phi)$, what would be the associated flight path? In particular, the flight path should depend on $x_0$ and $y_0$. Then, you can use this formulation for a suitable choice of $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(W,\phi)$.

Comment: @Fritz  I derived the flight for the second launch as follows s(t) = (Wcos$\phi$t+$x_0$, Wsin$\phi$t - $\frac{gt^2}{2}$+$y_0$) and equated this to the flight path of the spinning ball at t = $\frac{T}{2}$. This yielded the following equations:   $\frac{T}{2}$(Vcos$\theta$-Wcos$\phi$) = $x_0$   and  $\frac{T}{2}$(Vsini$\theta$-Wsin$\phi$) = $y_0$ - $\frac{T^2a_1}{8}$.  Despite multiple efforts I have not been able to reduce this into usable values for (x0, y0) and (W, $\phi$). Am I heading in the right direction?  Thank you

Comment: You're headed in the right direction. Remember that, since you know the first half of the flight path, you *know exactly* what the ball's position and velocity is at time $t=T/2$. Since you're piecing together two paths, those are exactly the initial conditions for the second part of the flight path. Note that you don't really have to find $W$ and $\phi$, since $W \cos \phi$ and $W \sin \phi$ are just the horizontal resp. vertical component of the velocity at $t=T/2$. Frits with an s, btw.